# How to POST a custom NSObject property to be saved MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, core-data

In a project I am working on I have a custom object called User (subclass of NSObject).  User has some string properties etc.. but the kicker is it also has a NSMutableArray property that contains other custom objects (EMO objects - name is short for Equipment Move Order).  Each User creates EMO's.  I can see how to create an EMO object in Core Data and read that out of the NSMutableArray and how to persist the objects in the Array into CoreData.

Here is what I cant get my head around though..

How would you post the user object to a server (a PHP script) that will save the User in MySQL.  Specifically, how do I save that NSMutableArray property full of custom NSObjects to a backend relational database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a JSON or XML payload that would get posted to the server (using a Restful interface).  The server would then take that payload and insert it into the database.

- `NSJSONSerialization` will turn it into JSON
- `NSURLSession` will be your API to push the http request to the server

Comment: So I assume the column in MySQL that holds the serialized object needs to be a Binary data type?

Comment: No, the MySQL would mirror the structure of the JSON/XML payload.